# Mule ESB Strategy to handle Socket read timed out exceptions

Tags: mule

what is the best approach to handle exceptions that arise out from IO exceptions. I have a jms endpoint which listens to messages on a queue. i realized my error handler is not handling errors  that result from message queue not being accessed due to socket time out errors. 
I tried creating a defaultsystemexception strategy but that does not work on mule 3.4.
the exception trace is as follows

```
ERROR 2013-12-17 17:39:52,419 [Thread-2]  org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Socket read timed out (javax.jms.JMSException)
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Socket read timed out(JMS Code: null) (javax.jms.JMSException)
oracle.jms.AQjmsExceptionListener:222 (http://java.sun.com/j2ee/sdk_1.3/techdocs/api/javax/jms/JMSException.html)
2. java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Socket read timed out (javax.jms.JMSException) (org.mule.transport.ConnectException)
org.mule.transport.jms.JmsConnector:508 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/transport/ConnectException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
javax.jms.JMSException: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Socket read timed out
at oracle.jms.AQjmsExceptionListener.run(AQjmsExceptionListener.java:222)
+ 1 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

kindly advise.

regards
Santosh

Comment: Add your config xml here. That will help in providing the correct solution.

Comment: i found a suggested fix on mulesoft, which involves creating a bean which extends DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy. this seems to be working. the catch strategy was not picking the exception. here is a link to the suggested fix. http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/how_to_handle_exception_from_outbound_endpoint

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information provided in the question the following solution should be helpful

```
<choice-exception-strategy>
        <catch-exception-strategy when="#[exception.causedBy(javax.jms.JMSException)]">
            ........  Processing of the Message.
            ....................
        </catch-exception-strategy> 
</choice-exception-strategy>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: catch exception strategy is not getting invoked for exception other than those of messaging exception.